# Redirect call to another iPhone

Tags: iphone

Can an iPhone redirect a call to another iPhone? For example, if I receive a call on my iPhone from one party, can I tranfer that call to let's say a coworker that uses an iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Settings/Phone/Call Forwarding/ Turn on Call Forwarding then enter the number you want to forward your call to. Note this occurs as soon as the call is received, and you cannot answer first.

Call conferencing would work too. You should look up your specific carriers method to accomplish this. Conference in the third-party, then hang up.

Comment: Could you conference in the third-party, then hang up?

Comment: I would think yes.